# Google Maps and Jquery .Load issue

Tags: php, jquery, maps

I have encountered an issue that I cannot seem to work out in regards to loading page content which contains a google map. Below is the index.php page containing the parent header and the google api information.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Maps -->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("location-wedding"),
            mapOptions);
      }
    </script>
    <!-- Switch Layout -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.Theme_Page').load("test.php");
        });
    </script>


</head> 


<body onload="initialize()">

    <!-- Page Change -->
    <div class="theme_holder">

    </div>

    <div class="Theme_Page">
        <!-- Content To Go Here -->
    </div>

</body>
```

The page being loaded in is the following:

```
<div id="location-wedding" style="width:700px; height:250px"></div>
```

The problem is if the above div is within the index.php then the map is present, as soon as it place it in the to be loaded page it does not show at all. The reason as to why I am wanting it to be in the .load() page is because I'm going to use Jquery to change the contents on this page (with an onclick event)

Any help or guidance would be most appreciated.

Cheers Lee.

Comment: `load("test.php",initialize)` try this ?

Comment: Hi Var, This worked, the only contention is that when the button to change the content is clicked the map (which is also present on the other html pages being loaded in) disappears. the code is :

$('.theme_holder :button').click(function() {
var page = $(this).attr('href');
$("#theme-loading").html('Loading');
setTimeout(function () { $('.Theme_Page').load(''+ page +'.php', null, function() {
$("#theme-loading").html('');
});}, 150);
return false;
}); 
});

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As yoda said your initialize function kicks in before load.php is loaded. so there will be no div where javascript can put map in instead of calling initialize function from body onload you should call this function in load.php ..... try this:: remove onload function from body and place following javascript code on load.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        initialize()
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Yoda and Suresh, I have added the above JS on the all the pages that I am loading in with the .load() Which works fine. But these loaded in pages do not have head tags (as the parent page has the body and head tags) by placing the JS at the top of these pages would it be considered bad practise? As the JS is not in the head of the doc?

Comment: You should call all of your script files in the `head` ideally, but function calls can happen anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, because the `onload="initialize()"` kicks in before the `test.php` div is loaded. Put the `initialize()` statement in the loaded page.